# How to use in Langchain cloud Chroma db?

Tags: python, cloud, langchain, chromadb

Here is a code, where I want to use cloud instance of Chroma db

```
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain_community.chat_models import ChatOllama
from langchain_community.embeddings import FastEmbedEmbeddings
from langchain.schema.output_parser import StrOutputParser
from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.schema.runnable import RunnablePassthrough
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_community.vectorstores.utils import filter_complex_metadata
from langchain_core.documents import Document
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveJsonSplitter
import json
import pandas as pd

import re

chroma_client = Chroma.HttpClient(host='XX', port=8000)
```

However, it gives me an error

```
chroma_client = Chroma.HttpClient(host='XX', port=8000)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: type object 'Chroma' has no attribute 'HttpClient'
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have a ChromaDB running over such `HOST_IP:8000`. One simple example you can try is to deploy a dockerized VectorStore

```py
git clone git@github.com:chroma-core/chroma.git
cd chroma
docker-compose up -d --build
```

You can find reference document > https://docs.trychroma.com/deployment

If you've done the above, do the following

```py
import chromadb
from chromadb.config import Settings

chroma_client = chromadb.HttpClient(settings=Settings(allow_reset=True))
```

Comment: It is already running there. There is a problem with langchain I cannot solve.

Comment: Modified the potential answer with additional effort